# Output of expressions unable to have operations be performed on the expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, tensors, vector-calculus, differential-geometry

I am currently trying to use the code linked in [the catalog of spacetimes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.4184.pdf) pdf to calculate chirstoffel symbols for a metric which follows as

```
    n := 4
```

```
    coord := {t, r, θ, Φ}
```

```
metric := {{-(1 - rs/r) c^2, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 1/(1 - rs/r), 0, 0},
{0, 0, r^2, 0},
{0, 0, 0, r ^2 Sin[θ]^2}}
```

```
inversemetric := Simplify[Inverse[metric]]
```

```
   affine := affine = Simplify[
Table[(1/2) Sum[inversemetric[[Mu, Rho]] (
D[metric[[Rho, Nu]], coord[[Lambda]]] +
D[metric[[Rho, Lambda]], coord[[Nu]]] -
D[metric[[Nu, Lambda]], coord[[Rho]]]),
{Rho, 1, n}], {Nu, 1, n}, {Lambda, 1, n}, {Mu, 1, n}]]
```

```
    listaffine :=
Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[Nu, Lambda, Mu]], 0],
{Style[ Subsuperscript[\[CapitalGamma],
Row[{coord[[Nu]], coord[[Lambda]]}], coord[[Mu]]], 18],
"=",
Style[affine[[Nu, Lambda, Mu]], 14]}],
{Lambda, 1, n}, {Nu, 1, Lambda}, {Mu, 1, n}]
```

```
    TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine],
Null], 3],
TableSpacing -> {1, 2}]
```

[image: This]

But when I copy and paste the output from the code say $-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$, the output options I get follow as [image: this]. As shown in the image I no longer have the options to carry out mathematical operations on the expression. What part of the code is causing this problems and how can the code be fixed such that I can have all the options shown in the first  image?

Comment: What is `metric`, `coord` and `inversemetric`? My initial guess is that such behavior is caused by `*Form` wrappers that leave expressions in non-computable formats.

Comment: @Syed I have fiexed the post to define the metric coord and inversemetric. Is there a way I can modify the code to change thef orm just that is does leave an expression in a computable format?

Comment: Now you are missing `r, \[Theta], \[CapitalPhi]`? The code run as such throws recursion errors. Also in your post `a` and `b` show up in blue color which signifies that these are yet undefined. Please present a minimal working example that can be copied to notebooks. Same comment goes for `Style` showing up in a statement unless it is for presentation. Thanks.

Comment: What is meant my minimal working example? What type of example should I provide?

Comment: Your problem arises frim using `Style[...]`. Eliminate these.

Comment: @DanielHuber So just delete the "Style[]" portion of the code and leave everything else unchanged?

Comment: Yes, try it out.

Comment: @DanielHuber just tried it out and it works, thanks for the help!